# instalar Node y no ejecuta el npm (npm: command not found)

Tags: nodejs, npm

tengo un problema al ejecutar `npm` es como si no se instalara, ya he intentdo desinstalar node y volver instalar pero aun no sale, por lo que he leído queda instalado `/usr/local/bin/node` pero busco en la ruta y no está, lo encontré `/opt/node`  cuando ejecuto el comando `node -v` si me sale la version de node pero la `npm` me sale que no existe el comando. Uso Ubuntu 16.04.2

Comment: Debe encontrarse en : /usr/local/bin/ !

Comment: @Jorgesys si pero como nose de comandos de terminal mucho nose como colocarla ahí, siempre queda preddeterminado instalado en /opt

Comment: como ejecutas npm, desde que ruta,  agrega el comando y sus parámetros.

Comment: Reinstala como administrador

Comment: Yo te recomendaría utilizar nvm https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo nvm porque? es mejor instalar los paquetes con eso?

Comment: Porque te evitas problemas como el que tienes. Los paquetes se instalan con npm.  Esto es una herramienta que te ayuda en la instalación y gestión de node.

Comment: Cómo instalaste node?

Comment: @amenadiel primero instalé la https://github.com/nodesource/distributions luego si `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`, @JoseHermosillaRodrigo pero deberia instalarse con npm, en otros lados lo he instalado normal y si sale el npm, es raro que esta vez no salga

Comment: si compilaste del código fuente no viene con npm. Pero si después usaste apt sí debiera funcionar. Si haces `node -v`  te responde algo?

Comment: @amenadiel si `node -v` si responde y muestra la versión.

Comment: Una cosa es node y otra es npm, al instalar node no se instala npm, hay que instalarlo aparte, por que por lo que se lee en la descripción del problema no ha instalado npm como tal

Answer (score 1):

Hola intenta con lo siguiente:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

y luego:

```
npm -v
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es instalarlo con los binarios que se descarga de la pagina oficial.

Descargas los binarios que proporciona la pagina oficial, después como root te posicionas en la ruta `/usr/local/lib` y crear la carpeta `nodejs` te debe quedar algo asi `/usr/local/lib/nodejs`, hay es donde tienes que descomprimirlos el archivo que descargaste de la pagina de nodejs.

Después tienes que configurar el PATH del sistema, para esto es buena practica declarar las nuevas rutas en el archivo `environment` que se localiza en la carpeta `/etc`

El archivo debe quedar de la siguiente forma
`PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/lib/nodejs/carpeta_node/bin"`.

> *Nota*: La variable $PATH son las variables de entorno que ya esta configurado previamente, se lo tienes que especificar.

Lo único que resta por hacer es reiniciar el sistema y al iniciar la tendrías listo node junto con npm y npx.

Fuentes: [Instalación de Node.js a través del archivo binario](https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation)